# Do all devices in the same network have to use the same security standard (WEP/WPA/WPA2)?

Tags: networking, security, wpa, wpa2, wep

If a router uses WPA2 or WPA, can a WEP-secured client connect to the network if it uses the correct username and password? In other words, does the security standard have to be consistent across network devices or is it sufficient to just have the right credentials?

Answer (score 2):

WPA2 (AES) and WPA (TKIP) can be used as *mixed mode WPA2/WPA* on a common SSID, allowing both clients to connect with the the same passphrase. In this case, the AP simply advertises both encryption protocols and the client can decide. However, WPA is not backwards compatible with WEP at all, and you can't mix WEP with the same configuration.

This question was somewhat relevant 15 years ago, when some clients didn't yet support WPA. This day and age every device supports WPA2, so there's no need for the old protocols. Furthermore, **WEP is completely broken and insecure, and the TKIP used in WPA is weak**. Also, WPA3 was announced in 2018 with new security features, and questions today should be about moving from WPA2 to WPA3 and about their interoperability.

Answer (score -2):

That depends in the drivers of the the network adapter installed in the client.

The network adapter has to have to the drivers compatible with the security protocol of router. Such as if a network adapter has drivers for only WEP and WPA it cannot connect a WPA2 network, despite having the appropriate credentials.You will need updated drivers in this case.

Still most drivers will support WEP, WPA and WPA2 these days.

Comment: This means driver compatibility takes precedence over having the correct credentials, right? If the driver is not configured for WPA2, then the client can't connect to the network even with the right password?

Comment: Yes @JinYuLi that's the matter

Comment: Downvoter, please explain the downvote